# The async.retry function runs once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't find a proper explanation of how to use the retry function from the async library[docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/v2/docs.html#retry)

```
var async = require('async');
    
function callFunc(data, time, name, callback) {
     console.log("#")
     callback({message: data, time, name}, null); //error
     // callback(null, {message: "ok"});               // ok
}


var func = callFunc.bind(null, "data", "time", "name", function (err, data) {
     console.log(data);
     return err;
})
async.retry({times: 3, interval: 1000}, func, function (err, results) {
     console.log('===================================');
     console.log('Async function');
})
```

Example of what I implement(but simpler). Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Killed the whole day for this.

P.S. The function should be called three times on error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async.retry` function expects a function that has the signature `function (callback, results)`, where callback is a **callback function that you should call when the operation is complete**, and results is an object that contains the results of the operation so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
var async = require('async');

function callFunc(data, time,callback) {
     console.log(data, time)
     callback({message: "err"}, null); // error
     // callback(null, {message: "ok"}); // ok
}

async.retry({times: 3, interval: 1000}, function(callback, results) {
     callFunc("test", "data", callback)
},
function (err, results) {
     console.log('===================================');
     console.log('Async function');
})
```